# SQL: getting the correct result order

Tags: sql

Two tables-

`TRIDS - {srcid, id}`

`TR - {id, msgid}`

I get a list of msgid's from a report and i have run a query to get the src id from TRIDS table. The id field in both tables is the connecting key.
so i have tried something like-

```
SELECT
      TRIDS.srcid
FROM
      TRIDS
      JOIN TR
           ON TRIDS.id = TR.id
WHERE
     TR.msgid = 'value1' OR
     TR.msgid= 'value2' OR
     ....
```

There's usually anywhere from 40 to 50 'values' i get

But the query returns the results in no particular order. 
I would like to have the results in the order of values used. For e.g.

`result for value 1` 
`result for value 2` 
`.`
`.`
`.`

I tried not using OR and switched to an IN statement

```
WHERE
    TR.msgid IN ('value1', 'value2', ....)
```

The results are in order when i use around 5-6 values for testing. But when i use all (around 40), the results are again in no particular order and all over the place.

I need the result to be in order because they have to go back into another report and correspond to their respective msgid's.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Just to be clear'er

The Values are in no particular order. It's like value 1= 'abc213' and its corresponding srcid is ='786typ'.

The issue is that when i get the values (a VB macro in excel), the msg id's are populated into the spreadsheet and i have to take the results and put them back into the spreadsheet (another macro). If the results are not in relation tot he order of value's, the spreadsheet is messed up.

for e.g. 
I send in values as IN (value1, value2, value3)
the results i get are- 
result for **value1**
result for **value3**
result for **value2**

Not sure why this would happen but its creating a mess

Comment: Is value1 < value2 < value3...? In other words, how do you order your TR.msgid's?

Answer (score 2):

Try using ORDER BY

```
SELECT TRIDS.srcid FROM TRIDS JOIN TR on TRIDS.id=TR.id WHERE TR.msgid = 'value1' OR TR.msgid ORDER BY TRIDS.srcid asc
```

Also, you don't have to use OR, it's better to use IN

```
SELECT
  TRIDS.srcid 
FROM
  TRIDS
JOIN TR
   on TRIDS.id=TR.id 
WHERE
  TR.msgid in( 'value1','value2','value3'...)
ORDER BY
  TRIDS.srcid asc
```

Comment: ORDER wont work because i want the result srcid's in order of values being fed into the SQL query, not by the ascending value of the results.

Comment: Can you insert them into a temp table in order, using an identity column, then join to that table and order by the identity column?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered creating a new table to hold the Values and using:

```
...
WHERE TR.msgid IN (SELECT Value FROM Values ORDER By Value)
```